# Parsing atom response from InsertCalendar in Python on GAE (Calendar API)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-data-api

Using the GData Calendar API via App Engine in Python, when you create an event there are handy little helper methods to parse the response:

```
new_event = calendar_service.InsertEvent(event, '/calendar/feeds/default/private/full')
helper = new_event.GetEditLink().href
```

When you create a new calendar:

```
new_calendar = gd_client.InsertCalendar(new_calendar=calendar)
```

I was wondering if there might be related methods that I just can't find in the documentation (or that are--perhaps--undocumented)?

I need to store the new calendar's ID in the datastore, so I would like something along the lines of:

```
new_calendar = gd_client.InsertCalendar(new_calendar=calendar)
new_calendar.getGroupLink().href
```

In my code, the calendar is being created, and G is returning the Atom response with a 201, but before I get into using elementtree or atom.parse to extract the desired element, I was hoping someone here might be able to help.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the GData API, so I could be wrong, but...

It looks like `GetLink()` will return the link object for any specified rel.  Seems like `GetEditLink()` just calls `GetLink()`, passing in the rel of the Edit link.  So you should be able to call `GetLink()` on the response from `InsertCalendar()`, and pass in the rel of the Group link.

Here's the pydoc info that I used to figure this out: http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.calendar_resource.data.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply :)

Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to work.

What eventually did work was this:

`new_calendar = gd_client.InsertCalendar(new_calendar=calendar)
calendar_link = new_calendar.link[0].href`